# Generate different scores from a template

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I am a brand new lilypond user and I am struggling to understand what the best structure for my project might be.

Here a simplified example of it
I have a `main.ly` file that I was planning to use as a template to print my scores:

```
% main.ly
\version "2.24.1"

\include "block1.ly"

\score {
    \new Staff {
        \centralSounds
    }
    
    \layout {}
}
```

`\centralSounds` is defined inside `block1.ly` as following:

```
% block1.ly
\version "2.24.1"

centralSounds = {
    \clef "bass"
    f g a b
}
```

compiling `main.ly` works as expected and produce a pdf containing the data specified in `block1.ly`.

Now my plan would be to have multiple `blockX.ly` with different definition of the variable `centralSounds` and for each `blockX.ly`file generate a different pdf.

What is the best way to achieve this programmatically, i.e. without changing the `\include` statement manually?

I was considering to write a script or a Makefile, but I don't think I can inject variables into `main.ly`. Maybe a `Scheme` loop...? but I am not familiar with Lisp or any of its dialects...Or it is just a matter of refactoring my existing code?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming that `\include "high1.ly"` is `\include "block1.ly"`.  You also have a `\layout` block with a context that does nothing.  Just `\layout {}` would do in this case.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your use-case here.  You want only one `main.ly` for every piece you engrave?  I would instead copy `main'ly` for every piece, putting it in its own folder.  Then create `block1.ly` as you need to.

Comment: @ksnortum So you mean including `main.ly` from `block1.ly` instead? and how would I initialize `\centralSounds`? can I use it without declaring it? The use cases are  mainly pedagogical: exercises, presentations, examples etc.
Thank you for you corrections

Comment: No, I think your layout is good, but you still have to change the includes manually; either that, or copy `main.ly` every time you want to change pieces.  But really, having one `main.ly` and one or more `block1.ly` for each piece is the way to go.  Sorry I couldn't help more.